# Kubernetes : copying a test app to a pod without listing as an image in Deployment yaml

Tags: kubernetes

I have an existing Deployment which has an image in the spec. I have changed it to only run single pod to do some test work, Now I want to run a test app within that pod which is in a zip.

Is it possible to run this app by directly copying it into the pod? Or is it required to build it as an image and update the Deployment?

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible* to do a lot of things, but many tricks are one-offs that lack mechanical sympathy with the automation, so are a misuse of the infrastructure and your operator attention. Best just to build an image and update the Deployment.